# Вылезающие окна git-bash в VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Недавно начал осваивать `git` и после муторной установки его в `VS Code` у меня после запуска `VS` и каждые несколько минут начинают вылезать на экрана консольные окна `git'а`, можно ли где то в настройках отключить показывание этих окон или отключить ежеминутное обновление данных?

к тому же, после изменений файлов, в боковой панели редактора не высвечивается предложение обновить данные репозитория, что может быть причиной этого? можете кинуть ссылку на полную и грамотную установку `git'а`, все ролики которые я нашёл не помогли, у меня с начала просто `VS Code` не видел `git`, а потом очень долго сопротивлялся подключать bash. в итоге у меня всё это есть, но боковая панель не особо работает, а с `GitHub` контактирую не через `git-bash`, а через `PowerShell`, но с возможностями `bash'а`

Comment: Можно больше конкретики? Какое окно, не понятно. Если Вы скачали Git, - то Вы можете работать с любой оболочки, которая предоставляет взаимодействие с Git-ом. И если Вы пишите в VS Code-де, - то Вы используете терминал.

Answer (score 0):

Всё решилось сбросом VS Code, я не знаю почему оно не работало до этого, но сейчас всё, что я указал выше решилось